# Bootstrap: Floating labels with label before input field

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, label, floating-labels

I want to use floating labels with some input fields.
The for is based on Bootstrap 4 styles but I can't change the structure of the elements.

I found this example for floating labels: https://www.cssscript.com/demo/bootstrap-4-form-floating-labels/

The problem is, that the HTML structure is different and in the example the `input` field comes before the `label` field. It's the opposite in my code and I can't change that part.

I figured out, that the CSS in the example works only if the structure is the same.
Here's the CSS code which doesn't work with my structure:

```
.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  padding-top: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
}
```

It needs the label after the input.

My HTML structure looks like this:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required" id="billing_first_name_field" data-priority="10">
    <label for="billing_first_name" class="">First Name&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" placeholder="" value="First Name" autocomplete="given-name">
    </span>
</p>
```

As you can see, the label comes before the input.

I couldn't figure out how to change that.

If I change the CSS to this:

```
.form-label-group label ~ span input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
```

It will style the input instead of the label element.

Is there any other way?

Comment: no, there is no possibility of that, you must use this format in any case for floated input